# WSO2 ESB, REST Apis Versioning strategy

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I have PizzaV1.0.0 API, which strategy does it use to generate a new V2.0.0 version and keep both in ESB.

If version the CAR, the duplicity of APIs and Sequences.

I have not found a way to version the APIs in eclipse, I need to version the API and some sequences that have changed.

In API Manager I created a new version, now I have two versions published.

What versioning strategy do you use in ESB to stay in sync with API Manager?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this post can help you
http://nandikajayawardana.blogspot.com.br/2014/02/proxy-service-version-management-with.html

I do what they describe and it is working great.

Comment: If I have an API that calls 15 sequences, do I have to duplicate everything?

Is there a solution with maven where I can tell the build version and automatically generate the new versions of the artifacts?